# Printing BST in Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have made the BST in Python, but I have a problem with printing it. When I try to print it like this: `tree.BSTinOrder(Node(4))`, it prints only 4 and below "None".
Generally I'd expect it to be printed "fine" so it can somehow draw the tree or at least that I could see which node is connected with other.
If I want to print whole tree, should I do some kind of loop?

My code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.key = x
        self.left = None 
        self.right = None 
        self.p = None 

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def BSTsearch(self,k):
        
        x = self.root
        while x!=None and x.key!=k:
            if k<x.key:
                x=x.left
            else:
                x=x.right
        return x 

    def BSTinsert(self, z):
     
        x = self.root
        y = None 
        while x != None:
            y=x
            if z.key<x.key:
                x=x.left
            else:
                x=x.right
        z.p=y
        if y==None: 
            self.root=z
        else:
            if z.key<y.key:
                y.left=z
            else:
                y.right=z

    def bstDelete(self, z):
       
        if z.left == None and z.right == None:
            if z == self.root:
                self.root = None
            else:
                if z == z.p.left:
                    z.p.left = None
                else:
                    z.p.right = None
        elif z.left != None and z.right != None:
            y = self.bstMinimum(z.right)
            z.key = y.key
            self.bstDelete(y)
        else:
            if z.left != None:
                z.left.p=z.p
                if z==self.root:
                    self.root=z.left
                else:
                    if z==z.p.left:
                        z.p.left=z.left
                    else:
                        z.p.right=z.left
            else:
                z.right.p=z.p
                if z==self.root:
                    self.root=z.right
                else:
                    if z==z.p.left:
                        z.p.left=z.left
                    else:
                        z.p.right=z.left

    def bstMinimum(self, x):

        while x.left != None:
            x = x.left
        return x

    def BSTinOrder(self, x):

        if x == None: return
        self.BSTinOrder(x.left)
        print(x.key)
        self.BSTinOrder(x.right)

tree = BST()
tree.BSTinsert(Node(5))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(3))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(7))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(2))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(4))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(9))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(8))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.key = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.p = None


class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def BSTsearch(self, k):

        x = self.root
        while x != None and x.key != k:
            if k < x.key:
                x = x.left
            else:
                x = x.right
        return x

    def BSTinsert(self, z):

        x = self.root
        y = None
        while x != None:
            y = x
            if z.key < x.key:
                x = x.left
            else:
                x = x.right
        z.p = y
        if y == None:
            self.root = z
        else:
            if z.key < y.key:
                y.left = z
            else:
                y.right = z

    def bstDelete(self, z):

        if z.left == None and z.right == None:
            if z == self.root:
                self.root = None
            else:
                if z == z.p.left:
                    z.p.left = None
                else:
                    z.p.right = None
        elif z.left != None and z.right != None:
            y = self.bstMinimum(z.right)
            z.key = y.key
            self.bstDelete(y)
        else:
            if z.left != None:
                z.left.p = z.p
                if z == self.root:
                    self.root = z.left
                else:
                    if z == z.p.left:
                        z.p.left = z.left
                    else:
                        z.p.right = z.left
            else:
                z.right.p = z.p
                if z == self.root:
                    self.root = z.right
                else:
                    if z == z.p.left:
                        z.p.left = z.left
                    else:
                        z.p.right = z.left

    def bstMinimum(self, x):

        while x.left != None:
            x = x.left
        return x

    def BSTinOrder(self, x):

        if x == None: return
        self.BSTinOrder(x.left)
        print(x.key)
        self.BSTinOrder(x.right)

    def bstGetRoot(self):
        return self.root

tree = BST()
tree.BSTinsert(Node(5))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(3))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(7))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(2))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(4))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(9))
tree.BSTinsert(Node(8))

tree.BSTinOrder(tree.bstGetRoot())
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
5
7
8
9
```

I think you misunderstood how to traverse through a tree. You would need the root for that. Notice how I added a method to retrieve the tree's root, and then passed it to the inoder traversal funtion, which worked just fine.

Comment: you are right, it's working. But why if I write `tree.BSTinOrder(Node(5))` it prints only 5? 5 is root, so why isn't it working in that case?

Comment: Because when you do Node(5), a **new node** is being passed which has no left or right child, so basically it is not the root. When you traverse using that node, it would obviously print only the current value and return back, because it does not have any children to go to.

Comment: @sunny, if you found the answer helpful, please accept it :)

Comment: would it be possible to print it without doing that bonus function, which returns the root?

Comment: Yes, there are two ways. Either you can return the new node created from the insert function and store the root element before hand. Or you have to use iterative traversal using stack, in which you would retrieve the root as soon as you enter the traversal function. Both ways, you need the root.